# Highcharts Treemap can't update data properly on React JS

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, treemap

I'm having difficulties with Treemap on Higcharts. Currently I'm getting my data with Redux and loading it into Treemap's options with no problem. The original data is an array with 10 items.

The problem occurs when I click on a node, and I do a dispatch to get new data and update the Treemap, if the new data comes with 10 items it will load no problem (just like the parent). But if it has a different length it shows me the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseover' of undefined

```
createChart();
 53 | } else {
 54 |   if (props.allowChartUpdate !== false) {
> 55 |     if (!props.immutable && chartRef.current) {
    | ^  56 |       chartRef.current.update(
 57 |         props.options,
 58 |         ...(props.updateArgs || [true, true])
```

I can't seem to find what can be.

EDIT: To illustrate more my problem, here's part of my code. I have a main container, a Highcharts component which receive the data as props, a Highcharts custom hook that creates the proper series data based on a Redux Payload.

1. Main Container has the Treemap container that gets chartSerie props which contains the data to load.

```
<GridWrapper item xs={12} md={10}>
<TreemapChart serie={chartSerie} idEntity={6927} year={yearsValue} />
/GridWrapper>
```

2. The Treemap component initially loads the Treemap perfect, and has this function to dispatch a Redux action and load new data.

```
events: {
 click: function (event) {
  dispatch(onTradedSegmentsThunk(idEntity, year, event.point.node.parent))
 }
}
```

3. The useTreemap hook gets the payload data from the Redux state and creates the proper structure to pass it as chartSerie

```
const selectedData = segment.length >= 1 ? segment : data
    const sortedArray = selectedData.sort((a, b) => segment.length >= 1 ? a.amountFamily < b.amountFamily : a.amountSegment < b.amountSegment)
    const newArray = sortedArray.map((item, index) => (
      {
        id: AlphaId[index],
        name: segment.length >= 1 ? item.family : item.segment,
        parent: index + 1,
        realValue: segment.length >= 1 ? item.amountFamily : item.amountSegment,
        value: serieValue[index]
      }
    ))
    setSerie(baseSerie.concat(newArray))
  }, [data, segment])

  return { serie }
```

What's weird to me is the 'mouseover' property which can't seem to find out why the error mentions it. But I think the problem is that the new data as different length as the first one that gets rendered.

Comment: The code you've posted is not that helpful - where's the reference to mouseover? Please provide more context.

Comment: Hi @leobiscuits, Highcharts for performance reasons mutates the original data array and that can cause your problem. You can try to clone your data before using it in the wrapper, but it would be great if you could create some live example of the problem. You can for example use: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-yi81d?file=/demo.jsx to start.

Comment: That's the strange thing to me, I don't use any mouseover event on any moment, but I guess Highcharts does. Since I'm currently loading the data from a local microservice I can't upload a live example. I'm currently using Docker to create an image for those services. But I uploaded more of my code if that helps. Thanks guys!

Comment: Unfortunately, the additional info didn't help. You can just create a minimal live example with your chart options and mocked data.

Comment: @ppotaczek ok I think Im going in a different direction that might work. Im doing a drilldown to load the new data. But now my problem is that If I set the drilldown data from the start works, but If I load it dynamically won't. Here's a live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d6xymq?file=index.js  I'm guessing I must update the Treemap after the drilldown loading? But I can't seem to find out how.

Comment: Ok I finally figured out. Here's my code If helps somebody https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d6xymq?file=index.js  Thanks again for the help @ppotaczek!